# Enable customer profile permissions

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I was testing the customer profile permissions demo here: [Customer Profile Demo](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook/blob/master/feature-demos/skill-demo-customer-profile/README.md)

I noticed that it would not read my email, and each time instructs me to "**enable customer profile permissions in the Amazon Alexa app**" which I have done and it just repeats the message.

As I thought it would all be automated by voice, my only question is,

- Would the end user have to go through this step of manually enabling permissions and typing in their password?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, not all the processes can be automated through voice for security and privacy reasons. One major field here is *password acquisition*.

As stated in [Developer documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-customer-contact-information-for-use-in-your-skill.html#how-to-request-customer-contact-information),

> Configure your skill in the developer console to indicate that it
>   requires customer contact information. As a result, when the customer
>   enables the skill, the customer is prompted, in the Alexa app, to
>   consent to provide the contact information.